# showAsAction в тулбаре не отображает иконку

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Быть может очень глупый вопрос, но я действительно потратил кучу времени найти ошибку, но не могу найти. Мне нужно чтобы отображалась иконка вместо пункта меню в тулбаре.

Но сейчас показывает вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код менюшки

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/chats"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/login"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/shop"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_active_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/login"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_add"
    android:title="@string/login"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Вот код валидации меню, может здесь где то конфликт

```
if (mIsUserExist) {
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new OnlineUsersFragment(), getString(R.string.online_users_title));
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(mSearchFragment, getString(R.string.search_title));
        mFilterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUnregisteredTitle.setVisibility(GONE);
        menu.findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new OnlineUsersFragment(), getString(R.string.online_users_title));
        mFilterButton.setVisibility(GONE);
        mUnregisteredTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTabLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        //Hide drawer
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
        menu.findItem(R.id.shop).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.chats).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(true);
    }
```

Может быть кто подскажет где искать и может быть еще ошибка.

Comment: Если меня память не подводит, то видимых может быть только две иконки, мб проблема в этом, удалите один пункт меню (для эксперимента можно два) и если отработает нормально, тогда у вас всё хорошо и можно будет поэксперементировать с программным добавлением елементов меню или исследовать showAsAction, параметры можно совмещать на подобие: always|showIfRoom и так далее

Comment: @Valeriy нет, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Тогда не знаю что вам сказать, копайте в темы, проверьте используете ли вы supportToolBar library. Попробуйте в чистом проекте реализовать